# Equation in rational numbers

Tags: diophantine-equations

I can't seem to find the way to solve the following equation so help would be much appreciated..

$x^2+y^2=x^3+y^3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: A promising looking beginning: If $x=p/q$ and $y=r/s$ in lowest terms, then your equation rearranges to $\frac{p^2(q-p)}{q^3}=\frac{r^2(r-s)}{s^3}$ in which each side is still in lowest terms. So you have $q=s$ and are left with an integer equation for the numerators ...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get why this rearrangement gives q=s.      Edit: ok I get it now

Comment: $\underline{x^3+y^3}=(x+y)(\underline{x^2+y^2}-xy)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\lambda=(t^2+s^2)/(t^3+s^3)$ for some $ t,s \in \Bbb Z$ such that $s \neq -t$ then $(\lambda t,\lambda s)$ is a solution.If $(x,y)$ is a non-trivial solution take $\lambda'=y/x$
 ( Note that $\lambda' \neq 0$ )then 
$$x^3+y^3=x^2+y^2$$
$$\implies x(\lambda'^3+1)=(\lambda'^2+1)$$
$$\implies x=(\lambda'^2+1)/(\lambda'^3+1)$$
Put $\lambda'=s'/t'$ for $s',t' \in \Bbb Z$.
We get the same form as above so those are the only solutions.